# Wordpress get terms - Hide empty, Hide terms that have a post assigned to it but that post is also assigned to another taxonomy term

Tags: php, wordpress, list, taxonomy, posts

I have a Wordpress taxonomy and im trying to list all the terms for that taxonomy but only if

1. the term has a post assigned to it
2. the post assigned to it is not assigned to another taxonomy term.

```html
 function createFilterDropDown($tax, $introValue, $introText, $name, $id, $class) {
  $terms = get_terms( $tax );
  if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
      echo '<div class="selectFilterWrap">';
       echo '<select name="' . $name . '" id="' . $id . '" class="' . $class . '" >';
        echo '<option value="' . $introValue . '">' . $introText . '</option>';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
         $selected = ( $_GET[$name] === $term->slug ) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
            echo "<option $selected value='$term->slug'> $term->name </option>";
        }
       echo '</select>';
   echo '</div>';
  }
 }
```

Currently the code above generates a list of terms and it's correct but its also showing terms that have a post against it that is also part of a taxonomy term that I do not wish to include.

The second taxonomy is called 'cpt_tax_intranet' and the term the post is assigned to is 'internal'.

So in short I need a list of terms from

1. the taxonomy cpt_tax_salary
2. only show term if it has posts assigned to it and that post is also assigned to  the taxonomy  'cpt_tax_intranet' and the term 'public'

All my posts will either be assigned to the term 'public' or 'internal' and I only want to show terms in my list that have posts assigned to them that are also assigned to the other taxonomy term 'public'.

Thanks in advance for any one that can help me.